# cannot set all the data-x attr of a popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twig

I'd like to use the popover to reduce the place taken on my website to delete something.

I created a popover in my view :

```html
<a 
    class="btn text-muted" 
    data-toggle="popover" 
    data-placement="bottom"
    tabindex="0"
    data-content='
        <a 
            href="#" 
            class="remove-template {{ index }}" 
            data-index="{{ index }}"
        >
            remove template
        </a>
    '
>
    <span class="fa fa-trash"/>
</a>
```

I try to use it in my javascript code as such

```js
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'bootstrap';

$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();

$('[data-toggle="popover"]').on('shown.bs.popover', function () {
    $(".remove-template").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var index = $(this).data('index');

        //for debugging
        alert($(this).attr('class'));
        alert($(this).attr('data-index');

        $("#li-field-"+index).remove();
        updateTemplate();
    });
});
```

as an output I get a first alert that shows

> remove-template 0

So I know that the `{{ index }}` variable is set in my view but for the second one I get

> undefined

Isn't it possible to set `data-x` attr on a popover directly in the `data-content` attr ?

## EDIT:

I created a code snippet trying to reproduce the behaviour of my page and of course it work smoothly...

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#pop").popover();
});
  
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').on('shown.bs.popover', function () {
  $('.remove-template').click(function(){
    var index = $(this).data('index');
    alert("index in the link = "+index);
  })
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <button tabindex="0" class="btn btn-primary" role="button" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="click" data-placement="bottom" data-container="body" data-html="true" id="pop" data-content='<a 
            href="#" 
            class="remove-template 0" 
            data-index="1"
        >
            remove template
        </a>'>
          <span class="fa fa-trash mr-1"/>
          Send to the trash
        </button>
</div>
```

So apparently the problem is somewhere else. In any case as it is not reproductible this question doesn't make sense any more.

Comment: The way you set an attribute is like this `$(this).data('index', TheValueYouWantToAddToIndex)`

Comment: I know, here I want to set this attribute in my view, in order to retrieve it in jQuery. I changed the question accordingly

Comment: Did you verify the `html` output? Perhaps twig is still serving an old template without the `data-index` in place. Your code should work as is

Comment: yes and it's very strange. The `data-index` is set in the `data-content` but doesn't show in the popover

Comment: In your original code you are using `alert($(this).attr('data-index'));` could you try with `$(this).data('index')`? It shouldn't make a difference but...

Comment: effectively I have the exact same result

Comment: Just tested this in my sandbox and it works perfectly... Dunno try to enable twig's debug mode and/or clear the cache folder

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you are using the `.click()` function which is listening a click javascript event on the given jQuery object.

But like i said before is that jQuery will not be able to listen this event cause you generated this html node after DOM generation.

To fix your problem, you'll need to listen an already existing object (like body) and then watch the html class you want: see example

```js
function addBlock() {
 var test = '<div class="foo" data-test="after">X</div>';
 $('#container').append(test);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  addBlock();
  addBlock();
});

// This will work
$('body').on('click', '.foo', function() {
  $('#bodyClickEvent').empty();
  if (!$(this).hasClass('staticFoo')) {
    $('#clickEvent').html('<span>&#8203;</span>');
  }
 $('#bodyClickEvent').html($(this).data('test'));
});

// This part of code will not work
$('.foo').on('click', function() {
  $('#clickEvent').empty();
 $('#clickEvent').html($(this).data('test'));
});
```

```css
.foo {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgb(50, 50, 50);
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  color: white;
}

.staticFoo {
  background-color: blue;
}

.event {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="description">
  <ul>
  <li>Y block are write in the HTML and generated with the DOM generation.</li>
  <li>X block are generated with a javascript function.</li>
  </ul>
  
  <p>Try to click on different blocks to see what append.</p>
</div>

<div id="container">

<div class="foo staticFoo" data-test="before">Y</div>
<div class="foo staticFoo" data-test="before">Y</div>

</div>
<div class="event">click event data: <b id="clickEvent"></b></div>
<div class="event">body event data: <b id="bodyClickEvent"></b></div>
```

Comment: This is not OP's problem. OP's code should work fine as proved in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59071709/446594)

Comment: the `.click` function is embed in `$('[data-toggle="popover"]').on('shown.bs.popover', function () {}` I let you check the [bootstrap popover event](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/popovers/#events) to realize that it could work or alternatively look at the answer that I [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59071709/6734243) that shows this behavior

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned in comments earlier accroding to [jquery doc](https://api.jquery.com/data/) for setting value you have to use:

`$( "body" ).data( "foo", 52 );`

Then, to get any `data` value you should use:

```
$( "body" ).data( "foo" ); // 52
```

Comment: not exactly my question, I want to set the `data-index` in the view, and then use it in jquery. But the `$(".toto").data('index')` return me an undefined